# jQuery Plugin- Add Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, plugins

Can someone tell me how to add new Timeline Cells for this Plugin

https://github.com/v-v-vishnevskiy/timeslider

Demo
http://v-v-vishnevskiy.github.io/timeslider/demo/demo.html

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3mn9ugc7/

```
  //new initial
    $('#slider123').TimeSlider({
                        init_cells: [
                            {'_id': 'c1', 'start': '0', 'stop': 60*5*999},
                            {'_id': 'c2', 'start': 60*5*1000, 'stop': 60*5*1000*2}

                        ],
                        start_timestamp:  2 * 1000,
                        current_timestamp: (new Date()).getTime(),
                        //distance_between_gtitle: 100,
                        ruler_enable_move:1,
                        hours_per_ruler:1,
                        update_interval: 1000

                    });
    //add new??
    $('#slider123').TimeSlider({
                        init_cells: [
                            {'_id': 'c3', 'start': 60*10*1000, 'stop': 60*7*1000*2}
                        ],


                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a cell by doing: `$("#slider123").TimeSlider("add", cell);`

But there are many actions you can do including adding, toggling, editing, removing, removing all cells and shifting the where the time slider starts.

Using "add", "toggle", "edit", "remove", "remove_all" and "new_start_timestamp" respectively. Most take a cell but remove just takes a cell id.

Comment: Great Man!!! Works 
$("#slider123").TimeSlider("add", 
      {'_id': 'c3', 'start': 60*12*1000, 'stop': 60*20*1000*2}
    
      
      
   );